# Show us who deleted a post, and when, in the mobile web view

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, deleted-answers

Deleted posts on the full site version are showing when the post was deleted, and by whom, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279259/152859):

> [image]

However, on the mobile theme, we don't have this information:

> [image]

Can this please added to the mobile theme as well?

Answer (score 4):

I agree this should be there (although it has never been there in the past).

Some vital information from deletions is missing, like the user who deleted it. Was it the author or was it deleted by other users, maybe even a moderator?

Please show this information to us.