# Please, can we have moderator functionality added to the Android/iOS mobile apps or the mobile browser?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, moderator-tools, ios-app, mobile-app

Some of my moderating can be done on a desktop, which is grand, as the browser version of Stack Exchange has all the functionality I could need, but I also moderate from an iPad or Android tablet and even from a smartphone when travelling or sitting in cafes, etc.

The apps do not give most of the functionality needed, so I find myself dropping to Chrome and loading the desktop version. (Desktop version, because [the mobile web site also lacks these features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263838/could-mods-have-some-access-to-flags-through-the-mobile-web-interface).)  On a smartphone, this means numerous steps to do anything, as well as a lot of zooming in to select the correct action.

Is there a way to add in two requests:

- include moderator functions in the app

And for bonus points, as there are a fair few of us who moderate more than one site

- add in multi mod functionality, such as flag notifications for all sites we mod into one, so we can respond faster, rather than waiting for our regular step round the sites.

As per the comment below regarding app development vs browser, I'd also be happy if this was added to the mobile browser!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263838/could-mods-have-some-access-to-flags-through-the-mobile-web-interface, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279273/show-us-who-deleted-a-post-and-when-in-the-mobile-web-view.

Comment: Thanks Monica - would like to have all this functionality in one tool.

Comment: Given that development on the mobile apps virtually stopped, I don't think spending dev time on something as complex as this for such a very small number of users to benefit from is worthwhile.. I like what y'all doing but this is just not worth it.

Comment: Except for notifications, I don't really see the advantage in the app over the mobile version of the site anymore. Having the full functionality on the mobile site would be nice. Flag notifications are unlikely to happen, they're not live-updated now and that is intentional by SE, they don't want them to be too invasive.

Comment: Well, even if it was available on the mobile browser then. That would help me immensely

Comment: Related: [Moderator flag notifications should reach mobile](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/111212)